# How to make all floating point numbers in a string have two decimal point precision in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string containing multiple floating point numbers such as the one below:

```
{0.0,0.06,0.02,0.031,0.15,0.5}
```

I want to replace every floating point number by the same number with two decimal points precision. So I want the answer below.

```
{0.00,0.06,0.02,0.03,0.15,0.50}
```

I tried using regex and here is my code which is not working.

```
import re

text = '{0.0,0.06,0.02,0.0,0.15,0.5}'

new_text = re.sub(pattern = '(\d+\.\d+)',
                  repl = '{:.2f}'.format(float('\\1')),
                  string = text)
```

I get the following error which is obvious but I don't know how to fix it.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\\1'

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/NYZqPg).